# How to get list of deleted records in SQL

Tags: sql, database, delete-row

My goal is to separate two types of data in table that is being sent to a stored procedure. In this table, I will have two kinds of records of type 1 and type 2, let's say.

I want to delete all data of type 2 from the inputted table but still have it stored in a separate temp table.

I know how to delete data with the following statement:

```
DELETE t
FROM @tags t    
WHERE t.Type = 2
```

Is there a way to retrieve the deleted records so I can insert them into a separate temp table?

Otherwise I will have to have a separate code block before that looks like the following:

```
INSERT @dynamicTags(String)
SELECT String
FROM @tags t
WHERE t.Type = 2
```

Any ideas to combine the two above statements into one?

Comment: which database backend? I havea solution for SQL server but it would nto work in any other database

Comment: Based on the variables definition I guess sql server.

Comment: Hi! It is indeed SQL server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using SQL Server you can do this with the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause:

```
DELETE t
FROM @tags t    
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO @MyTableVar
WHERE t.Type = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using postgres you can use the `returning` clause:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-delete.html